# Ember/Handlebars: Localization Helper with parameter array

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I want to localize a string that contains multiple placeholders.

E.g:

```
Hello %@1, today is %@2
```

I'd like to pass an array to the localization helper in my template like so:

```
{{loc "greetings" myArray}}
```

But that doesn't work, even though the [documentation](http://www.emberjs.com.cn/api/classes/Ember.String.html#method_loc) says it should.

What does work is

```
{{loc "greetings" "John" "Monday"}}
```

But the data I receive to display is an array and I don't want to store each element in a seperate variable.

How can I get the loc helper in the template to work with an array of data? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Isn't that supposed to be `{{loc "greetings", myArray}}` with a coma?
Could you please share your array data here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the people how will fall here :
He gets his answer here : https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/16337

`Loc` should be/will be/is deprecated